# How to pass a class variable from the first execution of the program to the next execution?

Tags: python, multiple-inheritance

I am trying to contribute to a Python project which consists of multiple classes and multiple inheritance. My goal is to use a class variable from previous execution of the program as an input to the next execution.

Since the next execution of the program will use different parameters, I need to store this variable and pass to the next program. The variable is dictionary of objects and its values.

I don't have enough experience to decide on the optimal approach, but those ideas what I have right now:

- Objects are all the same type, so maybe instead of storing the dictionary as a variable I can create a different class to store the information.
- Create a test class and execute the first program. Return the dictionary, and pass it to the next execution.
- Save the dictionary to a file and use it in the next execution.

Codebase is quite complex for me as a beginner, so what I would like to ask is any of my ideas are better than the other or is there anything else I can think of?

Comment: Hi charlotan, this question is pretty broad for StackOverflow - try https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/ instead. All listed ideas are potentially good approaches, but without more information regarding the code base itself I don't think anyone could give you a more detailed answer.

Comment: Hello jfaccioni, thanks for your suggestion! I thought there might be a best approach to similar kind of cases(multiple classes and multiple inheritance). I will try to be more specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this article might help greatly.

https://pythonprogramming.net/python-pickle-module-save-objects-serialization/

Here is how you would save a dict and reopen it the next time the program is run. As far as I am familiar, this should work for any data type.

```
#Saving dict
import pickle
example_dict = {1:"6",2:"2",3:"f"}

pickle_out = open("dict.pickle","wb")
pickle.dump(example_dict, pickle_out)
pickle_out.close()


#Reopening dict
pickle_in = open("dict.pickle","rb")
example_dict = pickle.load(pickle_in)
```

Comment: Thank you, serialization is what I ended up using in order to get the work done.